# How to show that the summation of the product of residuals and fitted values equal 0?

Tags: self-study, residuals, sum

I would like to show that $\sum e_i\hat{Y}_i$ = 0 with $\hat{Y} = HY$, $H$ - hat matrix and $e$ - the residuals $(I-H)Y$.

So far, I've gotten 
$$\sum e_i\hat{Y}_i = e^T \hat{Y} = ((I-H)Y)^T HY$$
 but I'm not quite sure if that's even right or how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use information that $H$ is symmetrical and idempotent ($HH=H$)